# Autowired and Unable to find column with logical name

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have problem. I cant create schema databse in hibernate. Schema was create but not columns. I dont know why, no red annotations in intelij. Im newbie and I used tutorials.

Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.adapp.dao.abstr.AbstractHibernateDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.adapp.web.config.persistance.PersistenceConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.adapp.dto.Privilege.privileges
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1932778756.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.adapp.dao.abstr.AbstractHibernateDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.adapp.web.config.persistance.PersistenceConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.adapp.dto.Privilege.privileges
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.adapp.web.config.persistance.PersistenceConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.adapp.dto.Privilege.privileges
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.adapp.dto.Privilege.privileges
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1461)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1233)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find column with logical name: roleId in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Role) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:590)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1456)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: roleId in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Role) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:583)
    ... 86 more
```

HibernateDAO

```
import com.adapp.common.IOperations;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Dom on 23.06.2016.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T extends Serializable> implements IOperations<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // API

    protected final void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        clazz = Preconditions.checkNotNull(clazzToSet);
    }

    @Override
    public final T findOne(final long id) {
        return (T) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

    @Override
    public final List<T> findAll() {
        return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list();
    }

    @Override
    public final void create(final T entity) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(entity);
        // getCurrentSession().persist(entity);
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public final T update(final T entity) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(entity);
        return (T) getCurrentSession().merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public final void delete(final T entity) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(entity);
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public final void deleteById(final long entityId) {
        final T entity = findOne(entityId);
        Preconditions.checkState(entity != null);
        delete(entity);
    }

    protected final Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

PrivilegesDTO

```
@Entity
@Table
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "privilegeId"))
public class Privilege extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private List<Role> roles;

    @Column(name = "name",unique = true)
    private String name;
```

RoleDTO

```
@Entity
@Table
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "roleId"))
@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries({ @org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery(name = "Role_findByName",
        query = "select OBJECT(r) from role r where r.name=:name") })
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_privilege",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "roleId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "privilegeId"))
    private List<Privilege> privileges;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
```

EDIT:

Problem is in

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_privilege",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "roleId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "privilegeId"))
    private List<Privilege> privileges;
```

without referencedColumnName everything is fine. I dont know why, column exist ...

Comment: The error message complains about the collection previleges in the class Privilege. So I don't think you're showing us the real code of your entities.

Comment: This is real code paste from intelij.

Comment: I dont see complains about previleges ? Where you saw this?

Comment: In the very first line of the stack trace: *Unable to map collection com.adapp.dto.Privilege.privileges*

Comment: I change privileges for List, but I have the same line in new stacktrace. I dont know where is problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that there is no column on the Role table called role and Role is a reserved keyword in some databases so you will have to change the table name to USER_ROLE or something that makes sense to you.

Try replacing : @Table annotation with @Table(name="USER_ROLE")

Hope changing the name would work. Good luck :)

Comment: Nope, I use Mysql and I changed table name but i have this same problem.